# Как отконвертировать любое значение в бинарное в  php

Tags: binary, php

В общем, вопроc: как отконвертировать стринговое или любое другое значение, к примеру, "sdfh", или 12309, или "dkfghdf2348s", в бинарное?

Я так полагаю, нужно его сперва отконвертировать в Хексовое значение, а потом уже в бинарное?

Пример:

```
function Converter($mystring = "", $convBack = false){

if ($convBack == false){
    // Конвертируем в бинарное значение

    // Получаем хексовое значение

    $result = bin2hex($mystring);
    $result = strtoupper($result);

    // ???

}else{
    // Конвертируем обратно из бинарного значение в стринговое

    // ????

    // Конвертируем конвертируем хексовое значение в стринговое
    for ($a=0; $a<strlen($mystring); $a+=2) { 
        $result.=chr(hexdec($mystring{$a}.$mystring{($a+1)})); 
    }
}

return $result;
}

$Text2Conv = "hello world!";

echo "<br>Отконвертированное в бинарный код<br>";
echo  $m = Converter($Text2Conv);

echo "<br>Отконвертированное в человеческий код<br>";
echo Converter($m,true);
```

Использовал онлайн-конвертер для проверки:
http://www.string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx
http://www.string-functions.com/string-hex.aspx
http://www.string-functions.com/binary-string.aspx
http://www.string-functions.com/string-binary.aspx

Пытался использовать функции:

```
base_convert($text, 16, 2);
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @max3000, эм, а что такое бинарное значение? Почему строка не является бинарным значением из коробки?

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, зачем плодить несколько одинаковых (почти) вопросов? [Тык.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/405561/php-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-string-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82)
Во-вторых, поможет функция PHP [pack()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php)/[unpack()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php).

**Обновление**

Честно говоря, я понятия не имею, как их юзать, да и никогда не нужно было (правда, немного коснулся этого, когда делал клиента ICQ).
Пользуйся гуглом - [тык](http://www.softtime.ru/bookphp/gl3_8.php) и [тык.](http://uk0.us/2012/06/function-pack-and-unpack-process-binary-data/)

Comment: немогли бы вы пояснить, что имено пакуют и распаковывают эти функции, и что значят параметры их я нашел здесь http://www.php.su/pack

Comment: Честно говоря я понятия не имею как их юзать, да и никогда не нужно было (правда немного коснулся этого когда делал клиента ICQ).  
Пользуйся гуглом - [тык](http://www.softtime.ru/bookphp/gl3_8.php) и [тык.](http://uk0.us/2012/06/function-pack-and-unpack-process-binary-data/)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.su/pack

Гугл рулит.

Comment: @Vahan Av, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.